# Exception in thread "restartedMain" with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am getting below error when the spring boot application starts with eclipse (STS). But when I start the application externally with java -jar command it successfully starts. 
How could I get rid of below exception with eclipse?

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
```

Comment: Different java versions?

Comment: Try increasing memory. Xms and Xmx params in Eclipse

Comment: Check the dependencies that are on the classpath in Eclipse. An `AbstractMethodError` typically indicates that you've got a mixture of versions on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur due to auto configuration. Try **removing** `spring-boot-devtools` dependency from your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

This seemed to have worked for me.